# Google analytics custom variable, key appears correctly, value does not

Tags: google-analytics

Implemented a filter on a webservice to make gif calls to GA for tracking method calls.

During initial testing I set a custom variable that contained account information. But for some reason, after a few weeks the variable stopped coming through to standard reporting correctly.

A test gif url:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.4sj
&utmn=230567348
&utmhn=localhost
&utmr=-
&utmp=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fv2svrmng%2FServiceManagerV2
&utmac=UA-12345678-9
&utmcc=__utma%3D999.999.999.999.999.1%3B
&utmvid=0x6ffa39da7d6bd0c7
&utmip=127.0.0.0
&utme=8(Account)9(testaccount-99999)11(2)
```

The Account key seems to be read correctly but the `testaccount-99999` value appears as `(A`

Is some sort of weird truncation occurring here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gif request is not a supported or documented API. You can only use it with the javascript library provided or other google libraries that communicate with Google Analytics.

The good news is that Universal Analytics is a new update to Google Analytics (currently in Public Beta) and it has a documented protocol to send data to GA using server side code like you want.

Read more about it and how to get into the Beta here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/